# Can't resolve all parameters for EmployeesService: (?). Evaluating main.ts Booting application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

Can't resolve all parameters for `EmployeesService`: (?).
Evaluating `main.ts`
Booting application

**services/employees.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  

    @Injectable()  
    export class EmployeesService {  
    private _employeesUrl = './employees.json';  
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }  
    getEmployees(){  
    return 
   this._http.get(this._employeesUrl).map((Response)=>Response.json());
    }  
    }
```

**services/employee.ts**

```
export interface Employee {  
    id: number,  
    name: string,  
    company: string,  
    isActive: boolean,  
    email: string,  
    mobile: number,  
    city: string
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { EmployeesService } from './services/employees.service';  
import { Employee } from './services/employee';  

@Component({  
    selector: 'my-app',  
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })  
    export class AppComponent  {  
    title = 'Http service Demo';  
    employees: Employee[];  
    constructor(private _employeesService:EmployeesService){ }  
    ngOnInit()
 {this._employeesService.getEmployees().subscribe(employees=>this.employees=employees);  
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the service in Provider's array in main app module?

Comment: i already added but still same error